# How to say "relation" (as in diplomatic relation between parties)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

How to term the connection between two entitles whether between countries or between individuals. How to say something like: "The relation between the brothers were once tense, but now they are warm". I'm not sure words like *conexus*/*colligatio* are working: *relatio* seems to be way off.